# Is there any clue about this issue "db failed to initialize or resync"?

Tags: postgresql, consul, stolon

While clustrising stolon I am facing this issue, database cant be initialized reporting
"db failed to initialize or resync"
ERROR   cmd/keeper.go:1066      failed to stop pg instance      {"error": "cannot get instance state: exit status 1"}

using the next stolon commands:
stolonctl --cluster-name=stolon-cluster --store-backend=consul --store-endpoints=http://127.0.0.1:8500  init

nohup stolon-sentinel --cluster-name stolon-cluster --store-backend=consul --store-endpoints=http://127.0.0.1:8500 &

nohup stolon-keeper --cluster-name stolon-cluster --store-backend=consul --store-endpoints=http://127.0.0.1:8500 --uid postgres0 --data-dir /var/lib/pgsql/data/ --pg-su-username=postgres --pg-su-password=postgrespostgres --pg-repl-username=root --pg-repl-password=replrepl --pg-listen-address=127.0.0.1 --pg-port=5432 --pg-bin-path=/usr/bin &

nohup stolon-proxy --cluster-name stolon-cluster --store-backend=consul --store-endpoints=http://127.0.0.1:8500 --listen-address= 192.168.121.14 --port 15432